# SQL View query resulting in empty output

Tags: sql, sql-view

Working on a query that makes a view called awardsview, which takes columns from a few tables. When I run the query, nothing gets outputted and I'm not sure why. I ran "select * from awardsview" and which is pictured below. [image: desired resul]

```
 create view if not exists awardsview as
 select 
     b.title,
     writer.name,
     writer.state,
     p.prize,
     b.price * b.units AS earnings
 FROM ((author writer join book b ON writer.isbn = b.isbn) join award p ON b.isbn = p.isbn);
```

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing your data. Odds are one of your two joined tables has no matching rows. Try switching to LEFT JOINs to debug which one that might be.

Comment: This is like sending a picture of your car to the garage and asking them to fix it. We need to see sample data and a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Just added a link to the files

Comment: I don't think anybody is going to be visiting a Google drive link. See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), help us help you and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data and desired results, either with `create` statements in your question or using a DB<>Fiddle.

Comment: aight didnt know how else to add the files. Added a screenshot of "select * from awardsview", which I finally got to show data. Still not showing anything when I run the original query.

Comment: What original query?  You didn't even show that.  You've only shown some CREATE VIEW statement and the result of `SELECT * FROM that_view`.  None of this is helpful if you're asking about some unknown SQL running against unknown data.  Are you suggesting that you think the `CREATE VIEW ...` statement should return rows of data?  No.  That's not what `CREATE VIEW ...` does.

Comment: I did show it lol but thanks